# Spark Creating DataFrame from a text File

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm trying to create dataFrame from a text file in spark but it throws error, here is my code;

```
case class BusinessSchema(business_id: String, name: String, address: String, city: String, postal_code: String, latitude: String, longitude: String, phone_number: String, tax_code: String,
business_certificate: String, application_date: String, owner_name: String, owner_address: String, owner_city: String, owner_state: String, owner_zip: String)

val businessDataFrame = sc.textFile(s"$baseDir/businesses_plus.txt").map(x=>x.split("\t")).map{
  case Array(business_id, name, address, city, postal_code, latitude, longitude, phone_number, tax_code,business_certificate, application_date, owner_name, owner_address, owner_city, owner_state, owner_zip) => BusinessSchema(business_id, name, address, city, postal_code, latitude, longitude, phone_number, tax_code,business_certificate, application_date, owner_name, owner_address, owner_city, owner_state, owner_zip)} 

val businessRecords = businessDataFrame.toDF()
```

And the error occur when I run this code;

```
businessRecords.take(20)
```

The thrown error code;

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 23.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 23.0 (TID 25, localhost): scala.MatchError: [Ljava.lang.String;@6da1c3f1 (of class [Ljava.lang.String;)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MatchError` means a pattern match failed - none of the cases matched for some input. In this case, you have a *single* case matching the result of the `split("\t")` to an Array with exactly 16 elements.

Your data probably has some records that don't follow this assumption (have less or more than 16 tab-separated fields), which will cause this exception.

To overcome this - **either** replace the use of `map` with `collect(f: PartialFunction[T, U])`, which takes a `PartialFunction` (which may silently ignore inputs that don't match any of the cases), which would simply **filter out** all erroneous records:

```
sc.textFile(s"$baseDir/businesses_plus.txt").map(x=>x.split("\t")).collect {
  case Array(business_id, name, address, city, postal_code, latitude, longitude, phone_number, tax_code,business_certificate, application_date, owner_name, owner_address, owner_city, owner_state, owner_zip) => BusinessSchema(business_id, name, address, city, postal_code, latitude, longitude, phone_number, tax_code,business_certificate, application_date, owner_name, owner_address, owner_city, owner_state, owner_zip)
}
```

**OR** - add a case to catch erroneous records and do something with them - for example, you can replace the `RDD[BusinessSchema]` result with a `RDD[Either[BusinessSchema, Array[String]]]` to reflect the fact that some records failed to parse, and still have the erroneous data available - for logging or other indication:

```
val withErrors: RDD[Either[BusinessSchema, Array[String]]] = sc.textFile(s"$baseDir/businesses_plus.txt")
  .map(x=>x.split("\t"))
  .map {
    case Array(business_id, name, address, city, postal_code, latitude, longitude, phone_number, tax_code,business_certificate, application_date, owner_name, owner_address, owner_city, owner_state, owner_zip) => Left(BusinessSchema(business_id, name, address, city, postal_code, latitude, longitude, phone_number, tax_code,business_certificate, application_date, owner_name, owner_address, owner_city, owner_state, owner_zip))
    case badArray => Right(badArray)
  } 

// filter bad records, you can log / count / ignore them
val badRecords: RDD[Array[String]] = withErrors.collect { case Right(a) => a } 

// filter good records - you can go on as planned from here...
val goodRecords: RDD[BusinessSchema] = withErrors.collect { case Left(r) => r }
```